# How to bind IsValidProperty behavior on button

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to achieve a validation control.

I've got a page, in which I've got an *entry* and an ok *button*.

The entry is an email input, and I implemented a **Behavior** to display to the user whether his input is good or not. I'd like to bind the *IsEnabled* Property of the button to the *IsValid* property of the behavior.

Here is the behavior code :

```
public class EmailValidatorBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
    const string emailRegex = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
        @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";


    public static BindableProperty IsValidProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsValid", typeof(bool), typeof(EmailValidatorBehavior), false);

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return (bool)base.GetValue(IsValidProperty); }
        private set { base.SetValue(IsValidProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
    }

    void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool IsValid = false;
        IsValid = (Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, emailRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)));
        ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
    }
}
```

And in the page, I had the behavior like that. 
It wokrs, color changes back to normal only if email validates regex

```
_emailEntry.Behaviors.Add(new EmailValidatorBehavior());
```

Plus, my page has a *bindingContext* which is a view model. As I know I'm going to do my logic here to bind . I see that I have to listen to the property changed event on the IsValidProperty but I can't resolve how to implement it. Something's not clear with binding and *bindableProperty* for me even if I read a lot of the doc on xamarin's website, especially in the case of behavior and creating bindable properties. I've begun that :

In page :

```
     var behavior = new EmailValidatorBehavior();
        //Binding context is LandingViewModel 
        behavior.SetBinding(EmailValidatorBehavior.IsValidProperty, "IsValid");
        _okButton.SetBinding(MR.Gestures.Button.IsEnabledProperty, "IsEnabled");
        _emailEntry.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
```

And here is the view model :

```
public class LandingViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    private bool _isEnabled;
    private bool _isValid;

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (_isEnabled == value) return;
            _isEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
        }   
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return _isValid; }
        set
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(_isValid);
            if (_isValid == value) return;
            _isValid = value;
            IsEnabled = _isValid;
            Debug.WriteLine(_isValid);
            OnPropertyChanged("IsValid");
        }
    }
```

I'm not happy, I see I'm clearly missing something, but can't see what ...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the `Debug.WriteLine()` you added, I'm guessing the `IsValid` property isn't set by the Binding.

It is because you're not setting the `DefaultBindingMode` of the `BindableProperty`, or because you're not setting the `BindingMode` of the `Binding` itself. So the binding defaults to `OneWay`, which means your behavior `IsValid` is modified when the view model is changed, but not the other way around.

Create your `BindableProperty` this way:

```cs
public static BindableProperty IsValidProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create("IsValid", typeof(bool), typeof(EmailValidatorBehavior),
        false, BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

And that should work.

Some additional remarks if I may:

#### 1. going through the ViewModel is not required

You could bind the `Entry` `IsEnabled` property directly to the behavior `IsValid` property.

```cs
var behavior = new EmailValidatorBehavior();
_okButton.SetBinding(MR.Gestures.Button.IsEnabledProperty, new Binding("IsEnabled", source: behavior));
_emailEntry.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
```

And if you do that, the behavior becomes the source of the binding and you don't have to create a `BindableProperty`, you just have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

#### 2. make sure that you never share the Behavior across `Entry` instances

if you share this Behavior in a Style, the same instance will be reused, and it won't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an `IsEnabled` property in your view model, so the line `OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");` won't do anything at all. What I believe you need to do is change the name of your `SetIsEnabledButton` property to `IsEnabled` and change the line `_isEnabled = _isValid;` to `IsEnabled = _isValid;`. That way when `IsValid` gets set it will transfer control to the `IsEnabled` setter which will then raise the property change notification for itself.

Post back here if you still have trouble getting it to work.

Comment: Was a typo mistake ... still I changed considering your post, my button is not enabled at start, so it seems correctly binded to the IsValid property, but I does not changes when the mail is valid (when color is back to normal, If i dump the IsValid value in the handleTextChanged function of behavior it works ... seems something wrong)

Comment: Please fix the typo in your question

Comment: You're still doing `_isEnabled = _isValid;`. You have to set `isEnabled` instead, otherwise the property change notification won't get raised.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out to make it work, and I did not need any viewmodel to do that thanks to @Stephane Delcroix post.

I still have my bindable property on the behavior following @Stephane Delcroix advice.

```
public static BindableProperty IsValidProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsValid", typeof(bool), typeof(EmailValidatorBehavior), false, BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

To bind my button on the isValid property I wrote that :

```
_okButton.SetBinding(IsEnabledProperty,
                new Binding(EmailValidatorBehavior.IsValidProperty.PropertyName));
```

"It's a good practise to refer to the PropertyName instead of the "Value" like "IsValid", in such a way it avoids any typos within the string and both the compilier and completion avoid mistakes".

I set the bindingContext of my button on the behavior just like that :

```
 _okButton.BindingContext = _emailBehavior;
```